# Why does useContext need the if statement when I use typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context, createcontext

It's just a simple createContext and useContext code. I struggled a lot until I realised that an if statement is necessary in the `useTodoContext` function. When I comment out the if statement line, then I get an error.
Can you tell me doesn't work the code without the if statement? It doesn't make sense...
Without the if statement, this is the error what I get:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in src/components/TaskList.tsx:12:11

TS2339: Property 'words' does not exist on type 'Context | null'.
    10 |
    11 | export default function TaskList({ tasks, setTasks }: props) {
  > 12 |   const { words } = useTodoContext();
       |           ^^^^^
    13 |
    14 |   const allowDrop = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    15 |     e.preventDefault();
```

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

type Context = {
  words: string[];
  setWords: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string[]>>;
};

const TodoContext = createContext<Context | null>(null);

const TodoProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [words, setWords] = useState<string[]>([]);

  return <TodoContext.Provider value={{ words, setWords }}>{children}</TodoContext.Provider>;
};

const useTodoContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(TodoContext);
  if (!context) throw new Error('Provider not inside'); // without this code line doesn't work
  return context;
};

export { useTodoContext, TodoProvider };
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've said it can be null and assigned null to it:

```
const TodoContext = createContext<Context | null>(null);
```

You can just always give it a value by providing a mock, which would only get accessed if you forgot to wrap your react tree in a provider:

```
const TodoContext = createContext<Context>({
  words: [],
  setWords: () => {},
});
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah it works... but how can have the if statement effect on the code? I mean it goes in the if statement only if the Provider doesn't wrap the element, where I was calling the useTodoContext. Since I wrapped the <App/> component, it shouldn't be relevant in my example, it never goes in the if statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? If your context could potentially be null you would need the if statement with a throw so that anything after definitely has a value. There is no way around that other than what I said, or writing unsafe code (like `return context!` or `return context as TodoConext`)